# Creating git repos on server properly

Tags: git

I logged into my server and created a repo using the commands:

```
mkdir project.git
cd project.git
git init --bare
```

On my local machine I then perform:

```
git clone server@server:/path/to/repos/project
```

which appears to work.  However, if I navigate into the folder, I get errors on `pull` like:

```
git pull
Your configuration specifies to merge with the ref 'refs/heads/master'
from the remote, but no such ref was fetched.
```

and

```
git status
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

and

```
touch test.txt
git commit -am "test file"
On branch master
Your branch is based on 'origin/master', but the upstream is gone.
  (use "git branch --unset-upstream" to fixup)

Untracked files:
    test.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present
```

Comment: Are you pulling in the server repo?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't actually have anything on the bare repo... so no master branch.... if you pull, well, no master branch.... that's why you have an error. Write something on your local, commit and push to master, then you will have something on the remote.